# python - compare the date in the string with today's date

Tags: python, string, date, time, compare

objective:

- compare the date in the string with today's date

Issue:

- get this error:ValueError: unconverted data remains:  12:00:00

question:

- how do a fix that error
- how do i remove the time element of the string?

Code

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime

dateTimeStart = "2014-01-01 12:00:00"

def main():
    dateTime1 = datetime.strptime(dateTimeStart, "%Y-%m-%d")
    today = date.today()

    if dateTime1 > "today":
        print "No"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main();
```

Comment: Why don't you include the time in your pattern then ignore it? Or slice the string to remove it? Or split the string on the space?

Comment: If you do not want to count hours, minutes or seconds, then define dateTimeStart = "2014-01-01" and datetime.strptime(dateTimeStart, "%Y-%m-%d") works without ValueError.  You could do the conversion automatically with dateTimeStart = dateTimeStart.split()[0]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to parse the time part as well:

```
datetime.strptime(dateTimeStart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then you can compare your dates like this:

```
if dateTime1.date() > date.today():
    print "No"
```

The [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) function returns the date of a `datetime` object.