# How to compare today's date and date stored in a string (without time)?

Tags: python, date, datetime

With python, How can I check if a date stored in a string has already passed?
My current code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
date1 = date.today()

data2_str = '2018-06-25'
data2_obj = datetime.strptime(data2_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(date1<=data2_obj)
```

The code above gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

Note that I would not want to work with any time - just the date (this case the treated in [32287708](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287708/python-compare-the-date-in-the-string-with-todays-date))

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.date()` method to get the date component like this:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
date1 = date.today()

date2_str = '2018-06-25'
date2 = datetime.strptime(date2_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
print(date1<=date2)
```

Output:

```
False
```